# Induction Motor Coil Series or Parallel?

Tags: motor, ac, induction-motor

Induction motors always have multiple slots per pole per phase. From what I've seen in the literature is that most if not all motors have these multiple coils in series, and not in parallek.

Why is this the case, if the stator coils were in parallel, the stator resistance would dramatically decrease and reduce copper losses? Do higher currents lead to higher magnetic fields and thus greater iron losses which outweigh the reduction in copper losses?

Comment: Parallel coils cannot be powered from 480VAC, nor series from 12VAC.  Except maybe for some *huge* motors.  Since 12VAC motors (parallel) are uncommon, windings are usually in series.  Small motors can generally be 70-80% efficient, while large motors can be over 90% efficient.  This leaves [little room for improvement](https://electricalacademia.com/induction-motor/three-phase-induction-motor-efficiency/) unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If put in parallel, you would need more turns to get the same inductance, in turn thinner wire to accommodate the slot place. To have the same motor, nothing really changes in terms of copper loss, higher field density would saturate the iron core, so even here is no gain. What you get with paralleling is the probability to have unbalanced stator winding, since a different wire lengths would affect the uniform current flow of each coil.

Answer (score 1):

An AC motor is designed to have a certain peak value of magnetic flux. That will be achieved at a certain value of voltage divided by the number of winding turns multiplied by the power frequency. The current determines the required wire size. The current is mostly determined by the mechanical power delivered to the load, but the magnetizing current is also an important factor. The resistance of the wire is only a minor factor in determining the current, but it does determine a significant portion of the losses.

The number of winding turns is the sum of the coil turns for coils connected in series. The number of turns is not added for identical coils in parallel. Thus if half of the windings are connected in parallel, motor's rated voltage is cut in half. In North America, many motors are designed for operation from either 460 V or 230 V by reconnecting half of the coils of each phase in parallel with the other half of the coils.